# How do I publish an Azure application that will be accessible from outside my network?

Tags: azure

We have implemented an Azure application. My question is - how does one go about publishing the app in the Azure public directory?

When clicking the Add button in the Applications page in the Active Directory section, the option "Publish an application that will be accessible from outside your network" is visible, but not clickable. Furthermore, there is no indication given as to why this option is not available.

Are there certain requirements to be met? If so, what are they? How do I proceed. I have a regular pay as you go Azure account. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the link at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/active-directory/. Its turns out you need to send an email. The process isn't automated yet.